# JHipster5 project with JPA static metamodel on Java 10

Tags: jpa, jhipster, metamodel, maven-compiler-plugin, java-10

I have been trying to upgrade my JHipster 5 application to use Java 10 but I can't get it to compile and process JPA static metamodels with Maven.

Apparently `maven-compiler-plugin` is not triggering `hibernate-jpamodelgen` in order to generate the JPA static metamodels.

In order to upgrade the project I have:

- installed Oracle´s JDK 10.0.1
- switched my pom.xml to `<java.version>10</java.version>`
- upgraded maven-compiler-plugin to add `java.xml.bind` module (since it is not included by default as of Java 10) as follows:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
              <!-- fork is needed so compiler args can be used -->
              <fork>true</fork>
              <compilerArgs>
                  <arg>-J--add-modules</arg>
                  <arg>-Jjava.xml.bind</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
              <annotationProcessorPaths>
                  <path>
                      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                  </path>
                  <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                  <path>
                      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                  </path>

              </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```

With this I am getting compilation failure when I run `./mvnw clean compile` with no further detailed error message.

If I remove the `<compilerArgs>` tag from pom.xml and run the same command I get: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

I have followed the upgrade instructions provided [here](https://gist.github.com/mraible/716f4d2ab205c0e747d51119fc5d9cd8)

Also, I made this example project available on [GitHub](https://github.com/selzlein/jhipster5java10)

[This](https://github.com/selzlein/jhipster5java10/commit/6ea1a85ca4e9c7706549b6c630262770b6640255) is the commit changes where I upgraded to Java 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to register the solution here wishing to help others, here is what solved this issue:

It turns out it was some Java 9 compatibility problem with `hibernate-jpamodelgen@5.2.16.Final`. Once I upgraded to Hibernate version `5.3.1.Final` it started to compile again.

I also had to solve JAXB dependencies following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43601685).

Comment: I think this is going to be a further issue with Java 11 as the java.xml.bind module is removed completely.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12991

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using Java 10, SpringBoot 2.0.3, Hibernate 5.3.1 .

What worked for me in Gradle, was to add javax.xml.bind to annotationProcessor as well :

```
annotationProcessor group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'

annotationProcessor group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.3.1.Final'
```

In this way, hibernate-jpamodelgen won't complain anymore about his missing `javax.xml.bind` dependency, since it's on the same group as him (annotationProcessor)